# Python Syntax error - new to python

Tags: python

I am having problems with basic programs and don't understand why I'm getting these syntax errors.

```
>>> words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
>>> for w in words:
    print w, len(w)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 


>>> x = 15
>>> if (x/2)*2 == x:
    print 'Even'
```

Note, I didn't even get a chance to type the next line before I got a `SyntaxError`.

What are the reasons for these errors?

Comment: Are you on Python 3? I don't think this is an indentation problem; you'd get an `IndentationError` if it was.

Comment: A much less convoluted way to check if a number is odd/even is `if number % 2`. Look up modulo, `%`, and check the result of `bool()` using different numbers including zero as a parameter to see why.

Comment: I suggest using Sublime Text or PyCharm because those will tell you where you have indentation errors.

Comment: Haha!  The problem is that `print` is a function in python3.  (Look how the answers will change now.)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713648/python-3-3-0-syntax-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, indentations are mandatory as that is how the interpreter understands code blocks. You should do:

```
>>> words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
>>> for w in words:
...     print w, len(w)

>>> x = 15
>>> if (x/2)*2 == x:
...     print 'Even'
```

Also, to check if a number is even, you can simply use modulo (`%`) which gets the remainder of a number when divided by another number:

```
>>> x = 15
>>> print x%2==0
False
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to indent python code.  That's how it's parsed.

```
>>> words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
>>> for w in words:
        print w, len(w)


>>> x = 15
>>> if (x/2)*2 == x:
        print 'Even'
```

Comment: I'm using python 3.4.1, and I'm following alone some educational videos from MIT on youtube. Im inclined to believe its an indent problem. Seems to happen on the next line after i have a ":". I just tried indenting and it did not work. I receive the same error.

Comment: Did you see the comment about print being a function in python 3?  That means you have to use parentheses with it, like a proper function.  Sounds like that's your problem. So, print (w, len(w))

Comment: I found the problem. Apparently the youtube video is a bit dated 2008 to be exact. Sense then python print command has been changed. you must use brackets () around your print object. if its a string then you will need both brackets and quotes. example print (w) for veriables and print ("This is a test") for strings.